# When to use Request timeout and Gateway timeout

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate, http-status-codes

I am writing a wrapper over a Third party API.

If I don't get response for certain time I throw the gateway timeout exception.

But i can see there is one more **HttpStatus.REQUEST_TIMEOUT** other than **HttpStatus.GATEWAY_TIMEOUT**

I don't know which one to use and when.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Once your server is acting as a *gateway or proxy* of an upstream server, you should use [`504`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6.5) to indicate that the connection has timed out. See how this status code is defined:

> [**6.6.5.  504 Gateway Timeout**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6.5)
>
> The `504` (Gateway Timeout) status code indicates that the server,
> while acting as a gateway or proxy, did not receive a timely response
> from an upstream server it needed to access in order to complete the
> request.

The [`408`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.7) status code has a completed different meaning and indicates that the server would like to shut down an unused connection with the client:

> [**6.5.7.  408 Request Timeout**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.7)
>
> The `408` (Request Timeout) status code indicates that the server did
> not receive a complete request message within the time that it was
> prepared to wait.  A server SHOULD send the "close" connection option
> in the response, since `408` implies that
> the server has decided to close the connection rather than continue
> waiting.  If the client has an outstanding request in transit, the
> client MAY repeat that request on a new connection.

Comment: what about request timeout, please elaborate

Comment: @Awadesh The `408` status code indicates that the server did not receive a complete request message within the time that it was prepared to wait. That is, it indicates that the server would like to shut down this unused connection with the **client**.